# React: How to call constant in method for database?

Tags: reactjs

I have a constant which returns a string. After I declare that constant, how can I reference it when using it in a method like data.status.course[0]? I have also tried data.status.{course}[0] but that doesn't work.

Snippet of code

```
const { course } = this.state;
...
data.status.course[0]
```

Let's say the constant course is "Biology", "data" would then have an object called status which would have something like

```
{
"Biology":[1,2,3],
"Chemistry":[0,1,0]
}
```

Comment: `data.status[course]`, where `course = 'Biology'`

Comment: `data.status[course][0]`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to to declare your constant using key pairs and then use this code:

```
function App(){
  const course = [
    {'name' : "Biology",  'set' : "[1,2,3]"},
    {"name" : "Chemistry",'set' : "[0,1,0]"}
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <p>Name:  {course[0].name}</p>
      <p>Set:   {course[0].set}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```